# Find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of an integral operator

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

Looking for eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the integral operator

$$\int _{0}^{\infty} k(x, y) \phi (x) dx$$, with

$$K(x, y) = \exp \left[ -\beta \left(\frac{\nu}{4} (x^2 + y^2) + \frac{\mu}{2} (x + y) \right) \right].$$
I have no solid basis on this subject, so I don't know how to start.

Comment: Look up "Mehler's formula".

Comment: See this paper, your kernel seems to be in the class described here, and the solution should be simple http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~ig/MAS214/int-ops-lect.pdf

Comment: Great, it helps. Thanks